# Am I forced to use href="#" when working with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I wrote a small bit of jQuery that uses .toggleTrigger and a rel attribute to toggle other items.

First problem I have with it is that when I use a button tag, it opens, then closes immediately. It works fine if I use an anchor tag.

Second problem is that if I scroll down the page and hit an anchor tag to toggle something below it, it takes me back to the top of the page because of the `href="#"` attribute.

I know these must be newbie problems but I just cant figure out how to get around them.

Could someone help please?

should my href point to something like `href="#divThatWillBeToggled"`

Am I forced to use `<a>` tags for the toggleTrigger?
I cant use `<button>` tags?

**EDIT (Pardon me I am new here and to programming)**

```
<a href="#" class="toggleTrigger">This is my Toggle Trigger</a>
<div class="toggle">This is info that is hidden and waiting to be toggled by the trigger</div>
```

Info hidden and waiting to be toggled

Comment: Your odds of getting a good answer will be greatly increased if you quote code.

Comment: Is `.toggleTrigger` a plugin? I cannot find anything. Or did you mean something else? Please post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the "href" attribute of the anchor otherwise it will not raise its click event. To stop the scrolling behavior use preventDefault:

```
<a href="#">click me</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default behavior (scrolling to the top)
        // perform other code
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This sounds like that I am looking for since jQuery is really all that I know... So if I use this to stop default behavior of the a tag, is it going to cause funky behavior on a tags that have nothing to do with toggling?

Comment: This is great, it worked for the button tags as well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The `href` attribute must be included in on your anchor tags as defined by the W3C standard. However, you don't have to use `href="#'`. You could also use `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Alternatively, if you don't care about the standard, you can omit the `href`, however your cursor will not change into the pointer like normal hyperlinks. You'll need to user `cursor:pointer` in your CSS on the anchor.

Comment: ahh ok, let me give that a try. aesthetically speaking its quite annoying to have the screen jumping around when a slide toggle takes place.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I forced to use href=“#” when working with jQuery?

No. This is terrible practice. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build).

> First problem I have with it is that when I use a button tag, it opens, then closes immediately. It works fine if I use an anchor tag.

This sounds like you are not doing anything to [cancel the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), thus submitting a form. (It also sounds like the server side alternative doesn't do the same thing as the JavaScript, so you aren't being [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement))

> Second problem is that if I scroll down the page and hit an anchor tag to toggle something below it, it takes me back to the top of the page because of the href="#" attribute.

The URL `#` means "The top of the current page". If you don't want the link to be followed after the JS runs, then you need to prevent the default action (as above).

> should my href point to something like href="#divThatWillBeToggled"

Yes. The div should also not be hidden with CSS by default (you can hide it immediately with JS though) so it will remain visible if JS isn't available.

> Am I forced to use tags for the toggleTrigger? I cant use tags?

HTML is all about tags. Your last question doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Regarding your last point: Please see the edit I made some minutes before your answer. The `<a>` and `<button>` tags have been there, but have not been formatted properly.

Comment: Great points here I have a lot to learn still about javascript. I am going to look into hiding things on document load via javascript.

Comment: It looks like removing the default behavior fixed the "problem" for me. But, if I can get into AJAX, would removing this default behavior from button tags prevent me from loading info dynamically?

Comment: No, because that isn't the default behaviour of a button.

Answer (score 1):

> ...it takes me back to the top of the page because of the href="#" attribute.

If you're handling the click on the anchor via JavaScript, in the event handler use either `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to cancel the default action (which is following the link).

The best thing to do is make the links really link somewhere useful, so that users who have JavaScript disabled can use the page (this is relevant to web pages, as opposed to web applications which can reasonably require JavaScript, provided they check for it and show a nice message if it's not found). So instead of `href="#"`, which is largely meaningless, have it actually take you somewhere meaningful — but then override that with JavaScript (by using `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` in the handler).

Answer (score 0):

`event.PrevenDefault` is what are you looking for http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score -1):

write anchor tags like this

```
href="javascript:"
```

eg

```
<a href="javascript:" id="myAnchorTagId">my anchor tag <a>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of #, use `href="javascript:"` if you want.